# Databricks - Pyspark: "Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2254.save" while saving into cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to optimize a process for saving a dataframe in cassandra. The code that I wrote work just fine if I run it, but took a lot of time (4 sec for each iteration, that is a lot given the amount of data).

I tried optimize it using `persist()` and `cache()` at some point in the script and now when I try to save in cassandra with this code

```
input.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").mode('append').options(**{
                                                                                    "table": "<table>",
                                                                                    "keyspace": "<keyspace>" ,
                                                                                    "spark.cassandra.connection.host": "<host>",
                                                                                    "spark.cassandra.auth.username": "<username>",
                                                                                    "spark.cassandra.auth.password": "<password>"
                                                                                    }
                            ).save
```

I receive the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2254.save.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected partitioning: DataSourcePartitioning
```

and the last error raised is this one:

```
 /databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
```

I understand that is something relative to the memory used, but I cannot find any reference of this on the internet, given my poor experience with databricks. The databricks kernel is 1 Driver
14 GB Memory, 4 Cores of Standard_DS3_v2,

EDIT: Apache Spark 3.2.1 and cassandra connector:com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12:3.2.0

Here the full trace of the error:

```
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2254.save.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected partitioning: DataSourcePartitioning
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.physical.Partitioning.createShuffleSpec(partitioning.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.physical.Partitioning.createShuffleSpec$(partitioning.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourcePartitioning.createShuffleSpec(DataSourcePartitioning.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.$anonfun$ensureDistributionAndOrdering$5(EnsureRequirements.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.$anonfun$ensureDistributionAndOrdering$5$adapted(EnsureRequirements.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$exchange$EnsureRequirements$$ensureDistributionAndOrdering(EnsureRequirements.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(EnsureRequirements.scala:471)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(EnsureRequirements.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUpWithPruning$2(TreeNode.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUpWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUpWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.mapChildren(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUpWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUpWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.mapChildren(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUpWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformUpWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:626)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUpWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:602)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.EnsureRequirements.apply(EnsureRequirements.scala:441)
    at com.databricks.sql.optimizer.EnsureRequirementsDP.apply(EnsureRequirementsDP.scala:718)
    at com.databricks.sql.optimizer.EnsureRequirementsDP.apply(EnsureRequirementsDP.scala:550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec$.$anonfun$applyPhysicalRules$3(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:1089)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec$.$anonfun$applyPhysicalRules$2(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:1089)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec$.applyPhysicalRules(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:1088)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$initialPlan$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.<init>(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:292)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.applyInternal(InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.apply(InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.$anonfun$applyInternal$1(InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.scala:64)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.applyInternal(InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.apply(InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.apply(InsertAdaptiveSparkPlan.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.$anonfun$prepareForExecution$2(QueryExecution.scala:596)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.$anonfun$prepareForExecution$1(QueryExecution.scala:596)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.prepareForExecution(QueryExecution.scala:595)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executedPlan$2(QueryExecution.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.simpleString(QueryExecution.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$QueryExecution$$explainString(QueryExecution.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.explainStringLocal(QueryExecution.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:575)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:959)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:258)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: what databricks runtime version and what version of spark cassandra connector?

Comment: se edit in the original post